# O365 MS Graph Unified API - how to get information on entity properties

Tags: odata, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I know that it is possible to retrieve whole metadata structure in edmx format through the OData $metadata. But these metadata's EntityType Property items are missing some interesting things - for example if property is filterable, updatable, or mandatory/optional for creating new objects. Maybe some description would come handy too.

Is it possible to retrieve this information through the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of what you're asking for can be expressed in $metadata by using the OData Capabilities vocabulary annotations (http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/vocabularies/Org.OData.Capabilities.V1.xml). There is a limited set of such annotations already present in https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata, for example:

```
<Annotations Target="microsoft.graph.directoryObject">
 <Annotation Term="Org.OData.Capabilities.V1.FilterRestrictions">
  <Record>
   <PropertyValue Bool="false" Property="Filterable"/>
  </Record>
 </Annotation>
</Annotations>
```

More such annotations will be added in the future.

Mandatory properties are normally marked with Nullable="false" attribute (http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part3-csdl/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part3-csdl-complete.html#_Toc406397955)